# I am developing an Alexa skill. I want Alexa to utter a stored integer value in her speech output. (Using PYTHON)

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I am trying to build an Alexa skill. I need one of the intent to multiply a slot value with a constant and store the product under some variable. I want the Alexa to speak the output this variable in her output sentence.

I have tried this but no luck:

```
int a
slots= handler_input.request_envelope.request.slots
num= slots["numbers"].value
name= slots["names"].value

if name=="xyz":
    a=num*20
    speak.output=("the total is %d" %a)
```

Answer (score 0):

To Alexa speech responses to User, you have to construct a JSON response.
You can find it in [this](https://medium.com/crowdbotics/how-to-build-a-custom-amazon-alexa-skill-step-by-step-my-favorite-chess-player-dcc0edae53fb).